# Rails not use application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I know that by default, views in Rails use the template provided in `application.html.erb`. However, there's one view that I wouldn't like to use the template provided in `application.html.erb`, but rather write all the HTML in that view itself. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the end of your controller action, add:

```
render :layout => false
```

Comment: Should that line go before or after the line `render "tree.html.erb"`?

Comment: on the same line `render "tree.html.erb", :layout => false`

Comment: but, if your action is already called `tree`, you can skip the "tree.html.erb" part, and just call `render :layout => false`

Answer (score 4):

For a specific action:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def my_custom_action
    render layout: false
  end
end
```

Comment: If you name your controller and actions the same way you name your views, you won't need to specify tree.html.erb. If you do, write it like this: `render 'tree.html.erb', layout: false`

Answer (score 2):

Sure, in your action do something like this:

```
def action
  render :layout => false
end
```

This assumes there are other actions in your controller which do need the layout. Otherwise, I would specify `layout false` in the controller root.

If you have multiple actions which don't need a layout, I believe you can do

```
layout false, :only => [ :action1, :action2 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the last bit.. might come in useful later!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same thing using custom layouts.

e.g. For `WelcomeController`

1. Create a custom layout file named `welcome.html.erb` in `app/views/layout/`.
   Write your layout code there(don't forget the `yield`). Due to rails `Convention over Configuration` feature when rails renders any view mapped to `WelcomeController`, `welcome.html.erb` will override the default `application.html.erb` layout.
2. If you want to name your custom layout file differently. Rails allows you to do that as well. Name your layout file as `mylayout.html.erb`. 
   In `WelcomeController`, add the following code

   class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

   layout 'mylayout'

   ....

   end
3. If you want custom layout for only a specific action, then on the last line of action write `render layout: 'mylayout'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that your controller inherits from ApplicationController

```
class MyCustomController < ApplicationController
```